# How to specify a sed expression to remove non-printing octal characters from a text file

Tags: regex, sed

I am new to sed and am cleaning up a very large file.  The cleaned document looks right, but when I read it into my R, it shows that each line is appended with `\016\t` at the end of each line.  I have figured out that the `\t` is a tab and that `\016` is an octl(?) but I haven't quite figured out how to put this into a proper expression.

Any assistance to a new sed user (and reg expressions!) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: This is not a broad question, it's about one specific thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with `bash`:

```
sed $'s/\016\t$//' infile >outfile
```

The regex `\016\t$` matches an octal `016` and a tab at the end of a line.  If this string is found, it is replaced with nothing.

The string format `$'...'` requires `bash`.  I tested the above with GNU `sed` but it [reportedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171415/bsd-sed-replace-hex-values-in-file) should work with BSD `sed` as well.

Another method, which works with GNU `sed` without `bash`, is:

```
sed 's/\o016\t$//' infile >outfile
```